# fancy header not quite working

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I'm trying to format the header in the table to contents for my university's dissertation formatting.  I have two files. The first file is dis.tex and the second is asudis.sty, both pasted below. The first page of the TOC is correct/what is required but the 2nd page has TOC on the left and right headers even though the .sty files says it should be otherwise. It needs to say "Chapter" as the left header on p.2 and "Page" as the right header. On the third page with the list of tables, that is correct but the 4th and 5th pages need to also say "Table" on the left and "Page" on the right but instead say "LIST OF TABLES" for both left and right headers. Similarly for the list of figures - p.6 is correct but p. 7-8 should say "Figure" on the left and "Page" on the right. The .sty file looks correct to me in that it's asking latex to use Table and Page as the headers.

dis.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}  
\usepackage[sectionbib,,globalcitecopy]{bibunits}% SC added
\defaultbibliographystyle{asudis} 
\defaultbibliography{dis} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{dcolumn,array}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{asudis1}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[font=xipt,labelfont=bf]{caption}


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents   

% This puts the word "Page" right justified above everything else.
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill Page\par}
\newpage
% Making the LOT and LOF "parts" rather than chapters gets them indented at
% level -1 according to the chart: top of page 4 of the document at
% ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf

% This gets the headers for the LOT right on the first page.  Subsequent pages
% are handled by the fancyhdr code in the asudis.sty file.

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand{\cftlabel}{Table}
\listoftables
\addtocontents{lot}{Table~\hfill Page \par}
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\addtocontents{toc}{CHAPTER \par}
\renewcommand{\cftlabel}{Figure}
\listoffigures
\addtocontents{lof}{Figure~\hfill Page \par}
\newpage

% This gets the headers for the LOF right on the first page.  Subsequent pages
% are handled by the fancyhdr code in the asudis.sty file.

\pagestyle{plain}

%-----------------------body
\doublespace
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{lipsum 1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{lipsum 1a}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section{lipsum 1b}
\lipsum[4-5]
\section{lipsum 1c}
\lipsum[6-7]
\section{lipsum 1c}
\lipsum[8-9]

\begin{figure}
\caption{\lipsum[1]}
\end{figure}
\pagebreak
\begin{figure}
\caption{\lipsum[2]}
\end{figure}
\pagebreak
\begin{figure}
\caption{\lipsum[3]}
\end{figure}
\pagebreak
\begin{table}
\caption{\lipsum[4]}
\end{table}
\pagebreak
\begin{table}
\caption{\lipsum[5]}
\end{table}
\pagebreak
\begin{table}
\caption{\lipsum[6]}
\end{table}

\chapter{lipsum 2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{lipsum 1a}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section{lipsum 1b}
\lipsum[4-5]
\section{lipsum 1c}
\lipsum[6-7]
\section{lipsum 1c}
\lipsum[8-9]
\begin{figure}
\caption{\lipsum[7]}
\end{figure}
\pagebreak

\begin{figure}
\caption{\lipsum[8]}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak
\begin{figure}
\caption{\lipsum[9]}
\end{figure}
\pagebreak
\begin{table}
\caption{\lipsum[10]}
\end{table}
\pagebreak
\begin{table}
\caption{\lipsum[11]}
\end{table}
\pagebreak
\begin{table}
\caption{\lipsum[12]}
\end{table}
\chapter{lipsum 3}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{lipsum 1a}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section{lipsum 1b}
\lipsum[4-5]
\section{lipsum 1c}
\lipsum[6-7]
\section{lipsum 1c}
\lipsum[8-9]

\chapter{lipsum 4}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{lipsum 1a}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section{lipsum 1b}
\lipsum[4-5]
\section{lipsum 1c}
\lipsum[6-7]
\section{lipsum 1c}
\lipsum[8-9]
\chapter{lipsum 3}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{lipsum 1a}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section{lipsum 1b}
\lipsum[4-5]
\section{lipsum 1c}
\lipsum[6-7]
\section{lipsum 1c}
\lipsum[8-9]

\end{document}
```

2nd file is asudis1.sty:

```
\geometry{top=1.0in,hmargin=1.25in,height=9.0in,includefoot,
letterpaper}%,showframe,showcrop}
%
% Define singlespace and doublespace commands for 12pt fonts.
%
\newcommand{\doublespace} {
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.66}\small\normalsize
}
\newcommand{\exactdoublespace} {
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.8}\small\normalsize
}
\newcommand{\oneandhalfspace} {
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.24}\small\normalsize
}
\newcommand{\singlespace} {
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}\small\normalsize
}
\singlespace

%
% Fix the table of contents
%
%
% Get leader dots right.  They should all be spaced the same and need to be
% added for chapters and parts.
%
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{1.7}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartdotsep}{1.7}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftpartdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{1.7}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{1.7}
\renewcommand{\cfttabdotsep}{1.7}
\renewcommand{\cftfigdotsep}{1.7}
%
% Fonts for the chapter titles and part titles.
%
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\rm}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\rm}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\rm}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\rm}
%
% Indentations: These are in accordance with the chart at the top of page 4 of
% the document
% ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf
% I simply moved each of the following sections "up" one level to get the
% indentations right.
%
\cftsetindents{chapter}{1.5em}{1.5em}
\cftsetindents{section}{3.0em}{2.3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{5.3em}{3.2em}
%
% Spacing between entries is taken care of by the double-spacing in this 
% section, so no need for extra space before chapter or part entries.
%
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{0truept}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0truept}
%
% Get the title for the TOC normal sized, centered, and at the right height.
%
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-64.0truept}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{0truept}
%

\renewcommand{\@cfttocstart}{ 
   \newgeometry{top=1.0in,hmargin=1.25in,height=9.0in,
   includehead,includefoot,letterpaper}%,showcrop,showframe}

   \doublespace
   \pagestyle{fancyplain}
   \afterpage{\lhead{\cftlabel}\rhead{Page}}
}

\renewcommand{\@cfttocfinish}{
   \restoregeometry\clearpage\afterpage{\lhead{}\rhead{}}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalsize\rm}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
%
\newcommand{\cftlabel}{CHAPTER}
%
% Get rid of the header underline.
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%
% Get the header on subsequent pages right.
%
% Get the title for the LOT normal sized, centered, and at the right height.
%
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-64.0truept}
\setlength{\cftafterlottitleskip}{0truept}
%

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\normalsize\rm}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
% 
% Get the title for the LOF normal sized, centered, and at the right height.
%
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-64.0truept}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{0truept}
%
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\normalsize\rm}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}


%%%%%%%%%%


\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                        \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                        \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                        {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}}%
                    \else
                        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%

                    %These two lines below are commented out.

                    %\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    %\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}

%
% Change some of the rules for float placement.
%
\setcounter{topnumber}{2}          %Maximum 2 floats on top
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}       %Maximum 1 float on bottom
%\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.7}    %Top float max size is 70%
%\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.7} %Bottom float max size is 70%
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.9}    %Top float max size is 70%
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.8} %Bottom float max size is 70%
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.7}


%
% Fix chapter and section formats
%
% Chapters names are all caps, centered under "Chapter N"
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
\begin{center}
\chaptername\ \thechapter\vspace{\baselineskip}\\
\uppercase\expandafter{#1}\vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{center}
}
% Numbers chapters, sections, and subsections
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
% Center section titles
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0 in}{1em}{1em}{\centering}}
% Center and italicize subsection titles
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0 in}{1em}{1em}
{\centering\slshape}}

% This is a bit of a hack.  I couldn't figure out a better way, but surely there
% is one.  What I want is for the title page of the appendix to appear with
% just one double space between the words "Appendix A" and the title.  So, here,
% I redefine the command with our \singlespace command, and then inside the 
% actual appendix, I use \doublespace.  This gets the spacing of the appendix
% title page right.

\renewcommand\appendix{\par
   \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
   \setcounter{section}{0}%
   \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
   \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}
   
   % I added this line.

   \singlespace}

%
% Fix bibliography header.
%
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\renewcommand\bibsection{
\begin{center}\uppercase\expandafter{\bibname}\vspace{1em}\end{center}
}

%
% Modify figure captions so that they print singlespace.
%
\renewcommand{\@makecaption}[2]{% #1 is e.g. Figure 1, #2 is captiontext
  \singlespace
  {\textbf{#1:} #2\par}
}

%
% Modify footnotes to be single spaced per footnote, double in between
%

\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip} %double space between footnotes

\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule %dont put a gap between the line and the first footnote
\def\footnoterule{\oldfootnoterule\vspace{-0.2\baselineskip}}

\let\oldfn\footnote   %single space individual footnotes
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\singlespace\oldfn{#1}\doublespace}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Are you sure that everything in the code above is necessary to showcase the problem? If necessary, read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) on this site. Thank you.

Comment: I pasted from the two files.  This should be it.  Thanks!

Comment: \renewcommand{@cfttocstart}{ \newgeometry{top=1.0in,hmargin=1.25in,height=9.0in, includehead,includefoot,letterpaper}%,showcrop,showframe}

\doublespace \pagestyle{fancyplain} \afterpage{\lhead{\cftlabel}\rhead{Page}} }

\renewcommand{@cfttocfinish}{ \restoregeometry\clearpage\afterpage{\lhead{}\rhead{}} }

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Your `asudis1.sty` file is not doing right things to customize the document (a lot of definitions were just hack things). My suggestion is don't use it. Anyway if you don't have other choice, at least you should know what it has been set by understanding the commands inside it. Also you should beware of the compile errors. In your `dis.tex` file, you need load `hyperref` package at the end of your preamble otherwise the `\texorpdfstring` command wasn't defined. The `font=xipt`  for caption package doesn't make sense, because you didn't `\DeclareCaptionFont{xipt}{some code}`. So your preamble should like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}  
\usepackage[sectionbib,,globalcitecopy]{bibunits}% SC added
\defaultbibliographystyle{asudis} 
\defaultbibliography{dis} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{dcolumn,array}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{asudis1}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

2. To make the header behaviors like you said, you need change the corresponding code as follow in your `asudis1.sty` file. I remove the letterpaper option from `\newgeometry` command because it is not available here.

```
\renewcommand{\@cfttocstart}{ 
   \newgeometry{top=1.0in,hmargin=1.25in,height=9.0in,
   includehead,includefoot}%,letterpaper option not available in `\newgeometry'%,showcrop,showframe} % changed

   \doublespace
   \pagestyle{fancyplain}
   \afterpage{\markboth{\normalfont Page}{\normalfont\cftlabel}\markright{\normalfont\cftlabel}}
}% changed
```